# Spring boot sends email but Angular does not. How to connect methods correctly?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rest, http

Spring Boot and Angular crud methods are ok, but still not clear how to bind other methods between spring boot and angular.

Rest API, Spring Boot-Angular. Sending email.

REST Controller

```
@PostMapping("/sendEmail")
public ResponseEntity<String> sendEmail(@PathVariable long id) throws CustomerNotFoundException{
    Customer customer = customerService.findCustomer(id);
    emailService.sendSimpleEmail(customer.getEmail(),
            "Hi dear customer! Your order is " +
                   "ready to pick up","Your order is waiting for you"
            );

    return new ResponseEntity<>("mail sent successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Angular. Service class with http.

```
 sendEmail(id:any):void {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/customers/sendEmail';
    this.http.post(url,{responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(
      res=>{location.reload();},
      err=> {
        alert('An error has occurred while sending email')
      }
    )
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming CORS has been configured your endpoint also expects `id`.

Add `{id}` to your endpoint.

```java
@PostMapping("/sendEmail/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String> sendEmail(@PathVariable long id) throws CustomerNotFoundException{
    Customer customer = customerService.findCustomer(id);
    emailService.sendSimpleEmail(customer.getEmail(),
            "Hi dear customer! Your order is " +
                   "ready to pick up","Your order is waiting for you"
            );

    return new ResponseEntity<>("mail sent successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Add `/` and param `id` to the end of your url.

```js
id = 123;

 sendEmail(id:any):void {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/customers/sendEmail/' + id;
    this.http.post(url,{responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(
      res=>{location.reload();},
      err=> {
        alert('An error has occurred while sending email')
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Joosep.P ! Today I asked my friend, he gave me the same answer as you. It works!